# Sending a blob over ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob, audio-recording

I am trying to send an audio blob over to my Rails action through an ajax POST. I seem to get over to the Rails action but the data I am sending appears to be empty and my audio file is not saved. I can do this with simple javascript, but I cannot seem to get this to work with ajax.

Ajax not working:

```
function sendRecToPostAjax(blob){

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("audio", blob, (callid + ".oga"));
    data.append('callid', callid);

    return $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    });
}
```

JS working:

```
function sendRecToPost(blob) {

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("audio", blob, (callid + ".oga"));
  data.append('callid', callid);

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "/controller/action");
  oReq.send(data);

  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
      if (oReq.status == 200) {
          console.log("Uploaded");
      } else {
          console.log("Error " + oReq.status + " occurred uploading your file.");
      }
  };
}
```

Comment: jquery (i.e. $.ajax) must be messing things up - note: the XMLHttpRequest code that works is also **A**synchronous **J**avaScript **A**nd **X**ML - the actual data transfer performed by `$.ajax` uses XMLHttpRequest - so, it's probably some obscure undocumented jQuery option you need to set to fix jQuey

Comment: Actually, for what it's worth AJAX is an acronym that stands for Asynchronous Javascript And Xml. Both your code snippets are using AJAX, the first one is also using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks guys for clearing that up! very useful to know! So what I was trying to do is to upload this file without refreshing the page :/ and I was hoping the first method would do this..

Comment: at a guess, DONT set `contentType:false` - in fact, don't set contentType at all

Comment: @suppp111 - the first method will do what you want exactly like the second method - you just need to find out which options to use

Comment: don't set `processData:false` either - leave those out of the options and $.ajax probably works like the native XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Okay Brilliant thanks! I'll need to look at what options I need for the first one then as it's my old and trusted :)

Comment: depending on jquery version, change `type: 'POST',` to `method: 'POST',` - as `type:` is deprecated (I beleive)